# MySQL Dump All Databases and Create (or Recreate) them on Import?

Tags: database, mysql

I was wondering how I can get the following file,

```
mysqldump -h server -u root -p --all-databases > all_dbs.sql
```

to automatically create any databases that are not yet created, when imported. Also, if a database is already present, it should recreate it (overwriting the old one).

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: I just used "mysql -u root -p < all_dbs.sql" and crossed my fingers, and turns out that it does exactly that! MySQL rocks!

Comment: Hey Garrett, please post your answer as an answer, this way other people with the same problem will be able to see. See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
Export: mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_dbs.sql
Import: mysql -u root -p < all_dbs.sql
```

Comment: slight correction, should read:

Export: mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_dbs.sql

Comment: `mysqldump -u [user] -p[password] --all-databases`
`mysql -u [user] -p[password] < all_dbs.sql`
remember that after `-p` there should not be a space!

Comment: the output of mysqldump should be redirected with the -r option to preserve UTF8 characters ... mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases -r all_dbs.sql

Comment: I had to add the --single-transaction to avoid "mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'somedb' when using LOCK TABLES" when exporting.

Answer (score 11):

**Export:**

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > alldb.sql
```

Look up the documentation for mysqldump. You may want to use some of the options mentioned in comments:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --opt --all-databases > alldb.sql
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases --skip-lock-tables> alldb.sql
```

**Import:**

```
mysql -u root -p < alldb.sql
```

**I Just found a new solution:**

Create a bash script. It backs up each database into a different file

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="zend"
PASSWORD=""
#OUTPUT="/Users/rabino/DBs"

#rm "$OUTPUTDIR/*gz" > /dev/null 2>&1

databases=`mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases; do
    if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != "performance_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != "mysql" ]] && [[ "$db" != _* ]] ; then
        echo "Dumping database: $db"
        mysqldump -u $USER -p$PASSWORD --databases $db > `date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
       # gzip $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use "mysql" command to export data. Please use "mysqldump" instead.

I have to administrate a server that saves only:

```
\n

Exiting...
```

after executing "mysql --user=username --password=passord > somefile.sql"

Comment: This should be an comment, not a answer.

Answer (score 0):

/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_dbs.sql